# Getting memory issue while starting cassandra

Tags: windows, cassandra

I am getting below issue while starting cassandra in windows

```
Starting with legacy startup options
Starting Cassandra Server
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
```

I am trying with cassandra version with 2.2.9, 3.0.9, 3.11.2 but for all I am getting above issue.

Please suggest. I am very new in it.

Comment: Did you configure manually the heap size to be 2GB? How much memory do you have on your system?

Comment: I´m having the same issue. I have 4GB in my system.

Comment: I am facing same issue after starting Cassandra server. Please help